# Ping servers and check the result from C program?

Tags: c, parsing, ping

[This is My last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259462/is-it-a-good-way-to-use-system-for-database-scripts-from-c). Now my new requirement is to ping some set of servers and check if they are replying or not. I am trying my way of

```
system("ping xxx.xx.xx.xx >out.txt");
```

And then parsing the out.txt for a string "Request timed out.".
This is yielding me good results. But is there any better way to do from c program. Non programmatic ways are also welcome. But mostly I want to go by C program. If the request is timed out I will send a mail through same my way by php. Thanks in advance.

My environment : windows, Tiny C Compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better method for capturing output than `system()` is to use `popen()` instead. That way you can capture the output of the command without using a temporary file.

A better method for pinging is to use the Microsoft ICMP API (an introductory page can be found [here](http://www.sockets.com/ms_icmp.htm)). This will be possible if your C compiler has the ability to call arbitrary Win32 API functions. In particular, [IcmpSendEcho](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366050(VS.85).aspx) is the function you would want.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is using raw sockets for sending/receiving ICMP packets yourself, or using a library such as *libnet* for that. You can then take your measurements at a finer granularity. It'll take some time and getting used to, though. :)