# How to make an SQL query from a C/C++ application?

Tags: sql, c, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to execute sql statements from a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838341/how-to-execute-sql-statements-from-a-c-program)

I'm creating a C application, and i need some data from my SQL server. Does anyone know how can I make an SQL query from my C application under Windows?

Comment: I don't know exactly but i think it is SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C, you'll probably want to use the Microsoft ODBC API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714562(v=VS.85).aspx

I use this heavily in my [CSQLBinding](http://networkdls.com/Software/View/CSQLBinding/)  class, which contains lots of usage samples. Besides the encapsulating class, (which is obviously C++ only) all of the functionality is completely compatible with plain C.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a code sample to start you off... Sorry I can't provide you a C example.

```
#include <ATLComTime.h>

#import "C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ADO\msado15.dll" rename("EOF", "EndOfFile")
inline void TESTHR(HRESULT x) {if FAILED(x) _com_issue_error(x);};

int main()
{
    std::string connectStr = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=MyDSN;Database=MyDB;User Id=DBUser;Password=Dbpwd;";

    try
    {
        ADODB::_ConnectionPtr pConnection;
        TESTHR(pConnection.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ADODB::Connection)));
        ADODB::_ConnectionPtr pConnection->Open (connectStr.c_str(),"","", NULL);


        VARIANT * RecordsAffected NULL;
        long Options = ADODB::adExecuteNoRecords;

        ADODB::_RecordsetPtr pRec = pConnection->Execute("select * from my_table",RecordsAffected,Options);


        // Rest you should be able to figure out.
    }
    catch(_com_error &e)
    {
        // print error message
    }
}
```